# What is this pink angiosperm from Morocco?

Tags: species-identification, botany

What is this pink angiosperm photographed in Morocco in spring? The diameter of the flower is about 2 cm. The petals are fused. The plant is crawling and did not have any erect parts. [image]

Comment: Could be some kind of [Convolvulaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolvulaceae)

Comment: It does indeed look a bit like bindweed. I hope to get a genus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a species of morning glory (fairly obvious from the flower). It is a member of the angiosperm family Convolvulaceae. The flower and the leaves together identify it as Convolvulus althaeoides. It is a Mediterranean native.  Links provided.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolvulus_althaeoides

https://www.google.com/search?q=convolvulus+althaeoides&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit1P3t7L7aAhVPmVkKHZIJD_gQ_AUICigB&biw=1097&bih=642